# Firebase error cannot get into the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
//error here
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Runtime");

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ping);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ping);
    lstPing = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPing);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_query);

    // Write a message to the database

}

public void fExecutePing (View view) {

    Editable host = editText.getText();
    List<String> listResponsPing = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listResponsPing);

    try {

        String cmdPing = "ping -c 2 "+host;
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(cmdPing);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String time_part = "";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
            for(String time:listResponsPing){
                if(time.contains("time=")){
                    String[] parts = time.split("time\\=");
                    time_part = parts[1];
                    myRef.push().setValue(time_part + " " + dateFormat.format(date));
                }
            }
            listResponsPing.add(inputLine);
            lstPing.setAdapter(adapterList);

        }

        Toast.makeText(this, " Command Execute Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " Error: "+e.getMessage().toString(),        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}

}
```

I'm new in firebase and android. My apps are about network testing. I have a problem in my PingActivity. I cannot insert the result from ping activity to Firebase. I've tried all the solution that I found. But its not working. Please help. Thank you.
The error at the code that I've comment.

Comment: If the error occurs when this statement `database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` executes, your app is not getting built correctly.  You will need to post your module `build.gradle` file and the logcat output from the crash.

Comment: you are right. thank you. my problem is solved.